# Construction of a proof of uniform continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

The task is:
Knowing that $f: D\rightarrow \Bbb R, \ \ D \subseteq R$ and there exists L>0 and $B \in (0,1]$ that f holds Hölder condition prove that f is uniformly continuous. I wanted to proof it in an esthethic way using only implications but I am not sure if it is legit, so i would appreciate it if anybody could comment on it.

$\bigg(\forall x,y \in D \ |f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|^B \bigg) \Rightarrow \bigg(\exists \delta \ \forall x,y \in D \ |x-y|<\delta  \Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|^B=L\delta^B \bigg)\Rightarrow \bigg(\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta=\sqrt[B]{\frac{\epsilon}{L}} \ \forall x,y \in D \ |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|\le \epsilon \bigg)$

1. If the beggining is true then if there exists specific delta for which $|x-y|<\delta$ then what's later on is true as well.
2. For every epsilon there exists a specific delta for which the following is true - and it is the definition of a uniformly continuous function.

Comment: The last assertion is correct and proves uniform continuity.

Comment: I would replace $\exists\delta$ by $\forall\delta$ in the middle assertion.